# Perform conditional operation on records having same keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like this -

```
City             MobilePlan
Scranton         Unlimited1
Seattle          Limited2
Scranton         Unlimited8
Olympia          Limited4
Olympia          Unlimited4
Albany           Limited1
Sacramento       Unlimited3
Seattle          Limited2
Albany           Unlimitd2
```

Now, I need to find the cities which only offer limited plans. I tried using the below query:

```
Select * from table_name where MobilePlan like 'Unlimited%'
```

but it obviously doesn't work. What kind of query is needed here?

Comment: @quinn your accepted solution is incorrect.  Please see Nick's answer and my answer for correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it almost  right, what you need i a subquery that is not in city.

The Distinct is there, because you have for Seattle 2 Limited Rows and so it shows only once in the result.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (`City` varchar(10), `MobilePlan` varchar(10))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (`City`, `MobilePlan`)
> VALUES
>     ('Scranton', 'Unlimited1'),
>     ('Seattle', 'Limited2'),
>     ('Scranton', 'Unlimited8'),
>     ('Olympia', 'Limited4'),
>     ('Olympia', 'Unlimited4'),
>     ('Albany', 'Limited1'),
>     ('Sacramento', 'Unlimited3'),
>     ('Seattle', 'Limited2'),
>     ('Albany', 'Unlimitd2')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT `City`  
> FROM Table1 
> WHERE  `MobilePlan` LIKE 'Limited%'
> AND `City` NOT IN (SELECT `City` FROM Table1 WHERE `MobilePlan` LIKE 'Unlimited%')
> ```
>
> ```
> | City    |
> | :------ |
> | Seattle |
> | Albany  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90a58976ee7e2b256cae896e4fad52ef)*

Comment: I expected to see `Unlimited` with a trailing `%`

Comment: I think you menat that you don'zt want to see the cities with Unlimited with a trailing nzmber. I changed the query

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` query to find cities that have a limited plan but no unlimited plans:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM plans p1
WHERE MobilePlan LIKE 'Limited%'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM plans p2
                  WHERE p2.City = p1.City AND p2.MobilePlan LIKE 'Unlimited%')
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
City
Seattle
Albany
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba2c611/2)

Note that your sample data has a typo in the last entry for `Albany`, it has `Unlimitd2` instead of `Unlimited2`. If that row is changed, the output becomes

```
City
Seattle
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc620c/1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery. Group on the city, and use the HAVING clause to express your qualifying criteria.

The logic demands at least one `Limited%` row and zero `Unlimited%` rows for a respective `City`.

```
SELECT `City`
FROM `Table1`
GROUP BY `City`
HAVING IF(MAX(`MobilePlan` LIKE 'Limited%'), 1, 0) = 1
   AND IF(MAX(`MobilePlan` LIKE 'Unlimited%'), 1, 0) = 0
```

Result set:

```
Seattle
Albany
```

Perhaps less intuitive, but more concise:

```
SELECT `City`
FROM `Table1`
GROUP BY `City`
HAVING MAX(`MobilePlan` LIKE 'Limited%') = 1
   AND MAX(`MobilePlan` LIKE 'Unlimited%') = 0
```